# Safari Web Extension horribly slow

Tags: swift, safari, safari-extension, safari-app-extension, safari-web-extension

So I created a Safari Web Extension. I did not change any piece of code and ran the template code provided by Xcode.
I clicked on the toolbar item and a blank popover window popped up. It took around a good 5 seconds to load the "Hello World!" screen (It is the screen that is the part of the template Xcode provides).
After that, whenever I again clicked on the toolbar item, the "Hello World!" screen popped up immediately, but Safari did not respond until around another 5 seconds.

Is this a bug on Apple's part or am I missing something?
I am using Xcode 12.2 and Safari 14.0.1

Note: This does not happen on a Safari App Extension

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue as well.

Comment: @flooie did you get any fix for this?

Comment: no. But it seems like it doesn't affect all OS versions equally.  And which WWDC around the corner it may just be a wait and see if they release something in June.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in Safari right now. I've had it reported with Apple for quite a while under FB8976225. But the great news is it looks to be resolved in [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview) Release 124. I'm hoping we will see it moved to the Stable channels soon.